# maxPointWidth causing more gaps for bars within each x point, in basic Column chart

Tags: highcharts

Using HighChart, I wanted to create grouped column chart with max width, so that when there are less points on x axis the bar does not look wide.

I found some property `maxPointWidth` which can be applied to achieve the same. but using this there is a gap for each bar within x-point.

How to remove this gap ? I have tried `pointPadding:0` as well seems this does not help

I am expecting chart something like below.
[image]

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mcshiva0507/hx83bbzb/2/

Answer (score 0):

`groupPadding` will help.  https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.column.groupPadding

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        groupPadding:0.45,
        maxPointWidth: 10
    }
},
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mcshiva0507/hx83bbzb/2/

Comment: Thanks Barbara, but using `groupPadding: 0.45` worked for `maxPointWidth:10` but when I increase that to 100, bar width is not getting changed. I have`maxPointWidth` as a dynamic value actually.

Comment: You can use `pointPadding` instead of `maxPointWidth` to make the width of the bars responsive: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/b9Lfbrwn/